# missing tables vertices_tmp and vertices_tmp_id_seq pgrouting workshop

Tags: openstreetmap, pgrouting, osgeo, osm2pgrouting

I'm using OSgeo 6.5 dvd and studing pgrouting workshop for get shortest path.
I created database call "routing" and used "template_routing" for create tables but only 3 tables created. So then I executed following commands

```
# become user "user" (or run as user "user")
sudo su user

# create routing database
createdb routing
createlang plpgsql routing

# add PostGIS functions
psql -d routing -f /usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/postgis-1.5/postgis.sql
psql -d routing -f /usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/postgis-1.5/spatial_ref_sys.sql

# add pgRouting core functions
psql -d routing -f /usr/share/postlbs/routing_core.sql
psql -d routing -f /usr/share/postlbs/routing_core_wrappers.sql
psql -d routing -f /usr/share/postlbs/routing_topology.sql
```

then 7 tables created but few tables are missing when compare to workshop..

Workshop output;

```
List of relations
Schema |        Name         |   Type   |  Owner
--------+---------------------+----------+----------
public | classes             | table    | postgres
public | geometry_columns    | table    | postgres
public | nodes               | table    | postgres
public | spatial_ref_sys     | table    | postgres
public | types               | table    | postgres
public | vertices_tmp        | table    | postgres
public | vertices_tmp_id_seq | sequence | postgres
public | ways                | table    | postgres
(8 rows)
```

My output;

```
List of relations
Schema |       Name        | Type  | Owner 
--------+-------------------+-------+-------
public | classes           | table | user
public | geography_columns | view  | user
public | geometry_columns  | view  | user
public | nodes             | table | user
public | spatial_ref_sys   | table | user
public | types             | table | user
public | ways              | table | user
(7 rows)
```

I got error like this

```
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "vertices_tmp_id_seq" for serial column "vertices_tmp.id"
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "CREATE TABLE vertices_tmp (id serial)"
PL/pgSQL function "assign_vertex_id" line 15 at EXECUTE statement
#########################
size of streets: 4093
size of splitted ways : 17328
finished
```

when executing this command

```
osm2pgrouting -file "data/sampledata.osm" \
                      -conf "/usr/share/osm2pgrouting/mapconfig.xml" \
                      -dbname routing \
                      -user user \
                      -clean
```

how do I get create missing tables

Answer (score 1):

The vertices_tmp table should be created by the assign_vertex_id() function, e.g.:

```
SELECT assign_vertex_id('ways', 0.00001, 'wkb_geometry', 'uid');
```

This will populate the "ways" table with vertex id for source and target ends of the road links got from the vertices_tmp table.

Should the command be run as the "postgres" user who owns the public schema rather than "user" who might not have permissions to execute the functions?  I had to move my tables from my "routing" schema to the "public" schema before it worked using the "postgres" user.

Comment: So can you please tell me where do i start I'm new to this gis  I tried running that query but it didn't work.

Comment: I used these sources to help build all the relevant tables, columns and indexes: http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/topology.html (see section 5.2) and http://www.archaeogeek.com/blog/2012/08/17/pgrouting-with-ordnance-survey-itn-data/